# Xamarin ios Push Notification stopped receiving

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

For Xamarin forms iOS application, Push notification stopped receiving. It was working before few months back. It is not working now.

Comment: please describe your problem in more detail

Comment: Thanks for your response. Push notification stopped working in our Xamarin application few months back. When we tested from some open tool, application is able to receive notification still. But our server code failed to send notification to Xamarin application. It is working fine with our iOS native application with same server code.